# Purges the old files which are archived in HDFS. Takes two input parameters; Directory and Number of days to retain

Tags: shell, hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, bigdata

Requirement:   Purges the old files which are archived in HDFS. Takes two input 
               parameters; Directory and Number of days to retain.

Example:

Directory:    sap_bw/ delivery/ ods_delivery_header

Number of days to retain: 30

Here, when I mention a directory and say 30. The script should purge all the old directories along with files in it which are more than 30days old.

Actual Folder structure in HDFS:

> / datalake/ archive/ sap_bw/ orders/ ods_salesorder_header->ods_salesorder_header_20140506075910
>                                 ->ods_salesorder_header_20140507185611
>                                 ->ods_salesorder_header_20140509160318
>                                 ->ods_salesorder_header_20140516111627
>                                 ->ods_salesorder_header_20140604081446

I'm trying something like this

```
if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]
        then
        export INPUT_DIR=$1
        export INPUT_DAYS=$2
        else
        echo "Incorrect number of script parameters; process aborting!"
        exit 1
fi

export DT=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
export NEW_DT=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S" -d "-$INPUT_DAYS days")
echo $DT
echo $NEW_DT
export DEST_DIR=/datalake/archive/$INPUT_DIR
END_OF_PATH=`basename "${1}"`
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. To improve your question, please tell us things you have tried (with source code, preferably) and where you're stuck. Please see the [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of help for more information.

Comment: if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]
        then
        export INPUT_DIR=$1
        export INPUT_DAYS=$2
        else
        echo "Incorrect number of script parameters; process aborting!"
        exit 1
fi

export DT=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
export NEW_DT=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S" -d "-$INPUT_DAYS days")
echo $DT
echo $NEW_DT
export DEST_DIR=/datalake/archive/$INPUT_DIR
END_OF_PATH=`basename "${1}"`

Comment: Just edit your original question and add the code in.